# How do I fix a ticking-tile entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos

I tried to boot up my Minecraft test world in the snapshots, and I got a ticking-tile entity error. Here is the crash report:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// I'm sorry, Dave.

Time: 20/03/19 17:29
Description: Ticking block entity

java.lang.NullPointerException: Ticking block entity
    at ev.<init>(SourceFile:52)
    at bso.i(SourceFile:194)
    at bso.g(SourceFile:104)
    at bgf.K(SourceFile:620)
    at vd.a(SourceFile:401)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.b(SourceFile:816)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:755)
    at dwc.a(SourceFile:128)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:630)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Thread: Server thread
Stacktrace:
    at ev.<init>(SourceFile:52)
    at bso.i(SourceFile:194)
    at bso.g(SourceFile:104)

-- Block entity being ticked --
Details:
    Name: minecraft:conduit // bso
    Block: Block{minecraft:conduit}[waterlogged=true]
    Block location: World: (0,64,-9), Chunk: (at 0,4,7 in 0,-1; contains blocks 0,0,-16 to 15,255,-1), Region: (0,-1; contains chunks 0,-32 to 31,-1, blocks 0,0,-512 to 511,255,-1)
    Block: Block{minecraft:conduit}[waterlogged=true]
    Block location: World: (0,64,-9), Chunk: (at 0,4,7 in 0,-1; contains blocks 0,0,-16 to 15,255,-1), Region: (0,-1; contains chunks 0,-32 to 31,-1, blocks 0,0,-512 to 511,255,-1)
Stacktrace:
    at bgf.K(SourceFile:620)
    at vd.a(SourceFile:401)

-- Affected level --
Details:
    Level name: 1.13 TEST WORLD
    All players: 0 total; []
    Chunk stats: ServerChunkCache: 2025
    Level seed: 3997715673040740701
    Level generator: ID 01 - flat, ver 0. Features enabled: true
    Level generator options: {biome:"minecraft:jungle",layers:[{block:"minecraft:bedrock",height:1b},{block:"minecraft:stone",height:3b},{block:"minecraft:sandstone",height:52b}],structures:{}}
    Level spawn location: World: (0,55,0), Chunk: (at 0,3,0 in 0,0; contains blocks 0,0,0 to 15,255,15), Region: (0,0; contains chunks 0,0 to 31,31, blocks 0,0,0 to 511,255,511)
    Level time: 1229280 game time, 1000 day time
    Level dimension: 0
    Level storage version: 0x04ABD - Anvil
    Level weather: Rain time: 0 (now: false), thunder time: 0 (now: false)
    Level game mode: Game mode: creative (ID 1). Hardcore: false. Cheats: true
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.b(SourceFile:816)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.a(SourceFile:755)
    at dwc.a(SourceFile:128)
    at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.run(SourceFile:630)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 19w12a
    Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.14.3
    Java Version: 1.8.0_74, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 1442840576 bytes (1376 MB) / 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB) up to 2147483648 bytes (2048 MB)
    JVM Flags: 8 total; -Xss1M -Xmx2G -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1NewSizePercent=20 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=32M
    Player Count: 0 / 8; []
    Data Packs: vanilla
    Type: Integrated Server (map_client.txt)
    Is Modded: Probably not. Jar signature remains and both client + server brands are untouched.
```

I followed the instructions of [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fWUUsdp3pJ8)
but when I opened the chunk, NBT Explorer Crashed:
[NBT Explorer Crashing](https://youtu.be/tLCqnoVchzg)
Can someone please help? I put hours into that test world and it would be a shame to loose it.
If it's any help, NBTExplorer is in my Downloads folder. Here is my system info:
[image: My Mac Specs]
I ran the world in snapshot 19w12a with NBT Explorer 10.2.3
Someone asked for the world download, so here it is [World Download](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rQAf-5I_5iqlWROxIbs7mxwFxECYP7kM)

Comment: I don't know for sure, but you might not be able to run Minecraft on your MacBook due to the GPU.  Searching other questions here might confirm this.

Comment: @MBraedley I'm pretty sure he played it just fine in an earlier version.

Comment: @John Can you upload the world somewhere and link it, please?

Comment: I just did @FabianRöling

Comment: @MBraedley I can load all my other worlds just fine. This one also loads fine but it crashes the instant it spawns you in.

Comment: Yay, finally a [tag:technical-issues] question that is answerable! Most people just come here, dump a generic error message (not the log) and disappear again. But this one here has enough details (log, world download, setup, reduction to the exact issue, …) and an actually responding asker. Great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the bug [MC-146246](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-146246), which is new in this snapshot. Crashes are usually fixed pretty fast, so it's likely that you will be able to use worlds with active conduits soon again.

Since NBTExplorer opens the world just fine for me (using Mono on Linux, not the Mac version), I've removed the two conduit tile entities (at 0 64 -9 and 16 58 -18) for you, making the world temporarily playable again. Then I opened the world and carefully removed the blocks as well, because many things can restore tile entities, which would crash the world again. The world now runs well again.

(download removed)

---

Update: In 19w12b this bug should be fixed, so you should be able to open world with active conduits again.

Comment: Please would you remove this download? I don't really want my world on the internet.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Done. And there's also a new snapshot out, so you can just update instead of downloading my version.